# Ошибка при отправке сообщения в телеграм чат с помощью python telethon

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telethon

```
from telethon import TelegramClient


client = TelegramClient('anon', api_id, api_hash)
async def main():
    await client.send_message(chat_id, 'Hello')


with client:
    client.loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

При попытке запустить код получаю ошибку:

> telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist.ChatIdInvalidError: Invalid object ID for
> a chat. Make sure to pass the right types, for instance making sure
> that the request is designed for chats (not channels/megagroups) or
> otherwise look for a different one more suited\nAn example working
> with a megagroup and AddChatUserRequest, it will fail because
> megagroups are channels. Use InviteToChannelRequest instead (caused by
> SendMessageRequest)

chat_id правильный, я проверял. В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0):

По идее всё должно работать, если правильный тип ID:

Если ты используешь целочисленный тип, должно быть так:

```
await client.send_message(-1000000000000, "Hello") #там отрицательное число, не забудь минус
```

Если ты используешь строковой тип (*только если чат публичный*), должно быть так:

```
await client.send_message("channelname", "Hello") #строка в кавычках
```